# How to mock a trait in Laravel 5 and tests a create method on a repository?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, testing, laravel-5

So I am learning how to test. Firstly I am trying to understand and go by the SOLID principles because I guess that helps with testing later.

So my `UserController`'s `store` method was bloated with lot of code like authorising the user, crypting the password, firing events and so on.

So after over riding the `create` method in my repository, it looked clean and had only one responsibility which is input and output, and looked like so:

```php
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    $user = $this->user->create($request->all());

    return response()->jsend(
        $data       = $user,
        $presenter  = $this->presenter,
        $status     = 'success',
        $message    = 'Resource Created Successfully',
        $code       = 201
    );
}
```

Note: `$this->user` is actually the repository instance and not the model itself.

And the `create method` of my user repository looks like so:

```php
public function create(array $data)
{
    // $this->authorize('store', $this->model);
    $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
    $user = $this->model->create($data);
    event(new UserWasCreated($user));
    return $user;
}
```

The test case I wrote looks like so:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

use Uppdragshuset\AO\Tenant\Repositories\EloquentUserRepository;
use Uppdragshuset\AO\Tenant\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

use Uppdragshuset\AO\Tenant\Events\UserWasCreated;

class EloquentUserRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $user;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->userRepo = new EloquentUserRepository;
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function test_create_a_new_user()
    {
        // $mock->shouldReceive('authorize')->once()->andReturn('');

        $user = factory(User::class)->make([
            'password' => 'password'
        ])->getAttributes();

        $this->expectsEvents(UserWasCreated::class);

        $user = $this->userRepo->create($user);
    }
}
```

So I am able to do things like `$this->expectsEvents(UserWasCreated::class);` and the events don't actually show up in the redis database. So I understand the basics of mocking I guess.

But notice how I have commented out the `authorize` method in the `create` method and also the mocking of it in the test because when I tried to mock the `authorize` method, I tried a lot of things but not many made sense to me because `authorize` method comes from a `trait` and not a `class` so how to mock traits and if I uncomment `authorize` in my `create` method, it gives me an error saying the user is not authorized which makes sense because there is no authorization at all. So how to mock this and am I doing all this correctly in the first place or am I creating stupid tests like amateurs?

**Update**

I even tried this in the test:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(Gate::class);
$this->app->instance(Gate::class, $mock);

$mock->shouldReceive('authorize')->once();
```

But no luck.